# Copy char array to another char array

Tags: c

I'm trying without success to copy a char array to another one. I have tried memcpy copying direcly the address from one to another, like this:

```
void include(int id, char name[16]) {
int i;

  for (i = 0; i < SZ; i++) {
      if (a[i].id == 0) {
          a[i].id = id;
          memcpy(&a[i].name, &name, strlen(name)+1);
          return;
      }
  }
}
```

But obviously works only inside of this function. I have tried also like this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/ but it didn't work.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What is `a`?  You should change it to: `memcpy(&a[i].name, name, strlen(name)+1);` because `name` is an array, and an array's name is already a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Why can't you use `strcpy` if the char arrays are null terminated?

Comment: Can you include `a` as an argument to the function `include`? Rather than having it as a [global variable](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) ...

Comment: @GWW - I prefer `memcpy` as it gives you the chance to protect against overrun in _both_ buffers. Though ghe OP isn't exactly doing that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Drop the `&` from `&name`** and it should work. Your function declaration is misleading; it's actually equivalent to:

```
void include(int id, char *name)
```

> The compiler pretends that the array
>   parameter was declared as a pointer

If `name` would be an array, `name == &name`. But `name` is a pointer so `name != &name`.

The C FAQ has some questions that might help:

- [Array parameters](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html)
- [Array parameter size](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it only works if the first parameter of memcpy is a char. In my case the variable _a_ is a struct with a char name[16] inside. And when I debug passing memcpy(&a[i].name, name, strlen(name)+1) the compiler give me an address out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks @cnicutar, you were right since the beginning! I changed all things like you said but forgot to change the struct declaration. Now it works! Thank you! :)