# Input 2 types of data into a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to in put 2 types of data into a linked list.  For example:

```
rotate 0
move 100
rotate 270
move 100
pattern #
rotate 0
draw 50
rotate -30
draw 100
rotate -90
```

which is first a string `rotate`, and then an integer  `0`.

I declare it this way:

```
typedef struct NODE
{
    char command[6];
    int number;
    struct NODE *next;
} NODE;
```

To initialise the string and variables:

```
char command1[6];
int num = 0;
```

Then to input to the list, have a function `addnode`:

```
void addnode(NODE *llist, char command1[6], int num)
{
    while (llist->next != NULL)
        llist = llist->next;

    llist->next = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof( NODE));
    llist->next->command[6] = command1[6];
    llist->next->number = num;
    llist->next->next = NULL;
}
```

And to key in put:

```
scanf("%s, %d"&command1, &num);
append_node(llist,command1, num);`
```

I get errors:

at the `scanf` line: `invalid operands to binary & (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)`

at the end of `addnode` function: `expected declaration or statement at end of input`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Mike you are right, I should have try first, so I break down the question, first I need to learn how to key in put, then I will try to figure out how to read from a file and input it.

Comment: Note that `pattern` has 7 characters, so you need to allow for a command size of at least 8.  You need to use `strcpy()` to copy the command in the `addnode()` function.  You have to worry about the `#` after `pattern`; if it is not a number, then your read will fail to convert the `#` to a number, then the next attempt will get the `#` as the command and fail to read the following `rotate` as a number, and then things will get back into synchronization again.  You should check that `scanf()` actually reads two items each time.  Always check inputs!

Answer (score 2):

The scanf should be

```
scanf("%s %d", command1, &num);
```

The name of the array, `command1`, when used without subscript operator gives the address of the first element.

Your addNode should be like this:

```
void addnode(NODE *root, char command1[6], int num)
{
    NODE *llist = root;
    do
    {
        if (llist == NULL)
        {
            llist = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            ...error check allocation...
            llist->command = command1;
            llist->number = num;
            llist->next = NULL;
            break;
        }
        llist = llist->next;
    }
    while (1);
}
```

Comment: for this line: `llist->command = command1;`                       error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[6]’ from type ‘char *’

Comment: @JackZhu you need to make `char command[6];` in `struct` to `char *command;`

Comment: or you would have to manually copy each character

Comment: which would also mean I need to malloc it right?

Comment: @JackZhu check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473798/copy-char-array-to-another-char-array)

Comment: You should also check that `scanf()` returns 2; if it doesn't, there's a format error.  You also need to use `strcpy()` to copy the command.

Answer (score 1):

You won't really be doing any "searching" here, but merely a string comparison for each command.  First you just need to create a list containing the "lines" read in from the file.  As you iterate through the file line by line, create a new node on the list.

Then, you can process the list by consuming nodes and doing a string comparison to see which command function you need to call.

It sounds like your teacher requires you to use a linked list, but it's not necessary.  You could execute the function calls without ever actually storing the lines in a container.

Comment: man, I agree, I don't want to use this link list if I don't have too. but the question is changed now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

1.To initialize a char array, use `memcpy(array, 0, sizeof(array))`.

2.To copy one string to another string, use `strcpy/strncpy`. `=` operator won't work in c.

3.Your scanf statement is wrong, should be `scanf("%s, %d",command1, &num);`.